# search in array in arry of objects by single character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

How to search in an array inside the array of the object by one single character

```
    const arr = [{ x: 1, tags: ["tag1", "taf", "ee", "xx"] },{ x: 3, tags: ["ta", "e", "xx"] }];

const fResult = arr.filter((res) => res.tags().includes("tag1"));
```

this will return the value if we input a full tag1 word, not just "t" or "ta"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match that the value starts with it then you want to use some()

```js
const filterIt = (arr, text) => arr.filter(
  (res) =>
  res.tags.some(
    val => val.startsWith(text)
  )
);

const arr = [{
  x: 1,
  tags: ["tag1", "taf", "ee", "xx"]
}, {
  x: 3,
  tags: ["ta", "e", "xx"]
}];

console.log("t", filterIt(arr, "t"));
console.log("ta", filterIt(arr, "ta"));
console.log("tag", filterIt(arr, "tag"));
```

Comment: very nice thank you

Answer (score 0):

finally figured out this simple solution

by converting the array of tags to string, then checking by including is solve everything

```
    const arr = [{ x: 1, tags: ["tag1", "taf", "ee", "xx"] },{ x: 3, tags: ["ta", "e", "xx"] }];
```

here is the solution `const fResult = arr.filter((res) => res.tags.toString().includes("tag1"));`

Comment: *"finally figured out this simple solution"* - immediately after asking the question?

Comment: @Spectric because OP was to enter "t" and get back tag1

Comment: This will match "stack" if you search "ta"..... Do you want that?